# React server with Node and Proxy API requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, mern

I'm relatively new to React, and trying to deploy an application to an Openshift environment. The app consists of a React JS front-end which makes API calls to a nodejs back end restful api. That's the idea at least.

Most of the ways I've found suggest using docker, but I have no idea where to start with that. The `create-react-app` documentations gives an example of an Node/Express server to render the index.html, which I am much more familiar with and have got working, but I can't seem to set a proxy to route the api calls to the back-end.

I initially tried setting the proxy in the package.json, but that didn't work. I then found `express-http-proxy` which looked promising, but can't get it to work.

My front end server looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
const API_PROXY_URL = process.env.APIURL

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.use('/api', proxy(API_PROXY_URL));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log(`Proxy in use of ${API_PROXY_URL}`);
});
```

I have a generic api function which is making the calls using axios:

```
export function apiCall(method, path, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return axios[method.toLowerCase()](path, data)
      .then(res => {
        return resolve(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return reject(err.response.data.error);
      });
  });
}
```

For example, my when I try and sign in it is trying to do a `post` call to `<<REACTURL>>/api/auth/signin` when I want it to send to `<<APIURL>>/api/auth/signin`.

I feel I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: If you want the request to go to a different domain then you have to specify the whole URL. If you just give the relative path the request will go to the current domain, which in your case is the react server.

Comment: Can I not proxy the requests though to be sent onto the API server?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, but in that case it is a matter of setting up the proxy server. `nginx` is pretty easy to configure as a reverse proxy.

Comment: From what I found it wasn't clear how to configure an nginx server openshift without using Docker? Or have I missed something?

Comment: I found this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 guide from digital ocean about installing and configurin` `Nginx` easy to follow. If it is the first time you are doing this I think it might be easier if you do not use Docker.

Comment: Hmmmm, I can see how I can do that on my own machine, but not on Openshift, as I can't edit the `.conf` file on the pod, I don't think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work as I wanted to ended up declaring the full URL in the API request to get it working. Not pretty, but does the job:

```
export function apiCall(method, path, data) {
  let url = <<APIURL>> + path
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return axios[method.toLowerCase()](url, data)
      .then(res => {
        return resolve(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return reject(err.response.data.error);
      });
  });
}
```